# Span element should keep the size after browser window resize

Tags: html, css

I have span element. This is green box on the following screenshot:
[image]

After browser window resize, span loses its size and also the icon:

[image]

How to let span know to keep the size in suzh case? I need to have something like this:

[image]

This is what I may see in devtools window:

[image]

Comment: Please show us your css. For now, I think min-width can help you.

Comment: The icon(container) seems to be a *flexbox* element. Check the `flex` settings and don't allow it to *grow*. Currently probably something like `height: 100%; flex: 1`, depending on `flex-direction`. Maybe requires parent to align to `flex-start`, or icon(container) have `align-self: flex-start`. And yes, show some CSS...

Comment: Thank you! min-width and height did the trick!